# Find products that are not associated to a category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Having the following MySQL tables:

```
products: id, name, description
categories: id, name, description
prodcat: id_product, id_catategory
```

How can I select all the `"products"` fields and all the
`"categories"` fields of the products that have not been associated to a category?

How can I associate products to a category ? (PHPMyAdmin - SQL)

Product:
ID Name Description
1-   Nike_Pegasus_Zoom - running_shoes
2- Adidas Jacket - jacket
3 - Adidas Telstar - ball

Categories:
ID  Name   Description
1   Shoes
2   Clothes

Must to associate the products to a category!

Comment: You can use join query to do this

Comment: if the product is not assigned to any category how you will get the category information ??

Comment: @CalinMateut . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Product:
ID Name Description 
1-   Nike_Pegasus_Zoom - running_shoes 
2- Adidas Jacket - jacket 
3 - Adidas Telstar - ball

Categories:
ID  Name   Description
1   Shoes
2   Clothes
Must to associate the products to a category!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didn't understand well your question but I guess you want to have all `products` that don't have a `category` associated

```
select * from products where id not in (select id_product from prodcat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a join would be enough...

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
JOIN prodcat pc ON p.id = pc.id_product
WHERE pc.id_category IS NULL
```